# Find k nearest neighbors

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix

```
a = np.array([[ 8.6569141 ,  8.19847655,  7.83540289,  8.49673563],
              [ 7.86962825,  9.16869072,  8.60084933,  8.91840291],
              [ 9.61896688,  9.69620637,  9.1879124 ,  9.87479709],
              [ 9.17427532,  8.98877464,  8.4313078 ,  7.81914999]])
```

I saw this code to obtain the indices of k nearest neighbors:

```
k = 1
index = a.argsort()[:, :k]
```

Output:

```
array([[2],
       [0],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Could someone provide an explanation on these output indices?

Answer (score 0):

NumPy's [`argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) returns the indices that would sort an array:

```
In [864]: a.argsort()
Out[864]: 
array([[2, 1, 3, 0],
       [0, 2, 3, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 3],
       [3, 2, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

This output is telling you that the indices of the elements of the first row of `a` sorted in ascending order are `2`, `1`, `3` and `0`. The indices of the elements of the second row are `0`, `2`, `3` and `1`, and so on.

Provided that you defined `k = 1`, `a.argsort()[:, :k]` is simply the first column of the array above:

```
In [865]: a.argsort()[:, :k]
Out[865]: 
array([[2],
       [0],
       [2],
       [3]], dtype=int64)
```

Therefore your code returns a `4 × 1` array such that the j<sup>th</sup> element contains the index (i.e. the column) in which is located the minimum value of the j<sup>th</sup> row of the array `a`, or in other words, the index of the nearest neighbour to the j<sup>th</sup> training sample.

Comment: If you need only k neighbors, and k << n, then `argpartition` is preferable over `argsort`.